# Symfony 5 : Error - No route found for "GET /<SiteConfigAcces>"

Tags: php, symfony, web-deployment

I developped a site with sympfony/phpp i want to deploy on a local server.

After the development on my own computer (where it works well), I put the project on a local server with apache, php 7.3.x, composer 2.0.0 under a debian 10 OS

All the transfer of the project from my computer to the server and the setting are well finished.
The project folder name is **si2a**. It is in the directory /var/www
I set the permissions access on this directory with ACL following [a symfony doc guideline](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html).

I set the site configuration file those the name is **si2afama.conf**. This last is in the directory /etc/apache2/sites-available. After setting, I activate the site, reload apache and clear the cache. Here is the si2afama.conf's contain :

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName si2afama 
    # ServerAlias www.si2afama.com 
 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/si2a/public
    DirectoryIndex /index.php
 
    <Directory /var/www/si2a/public> 
        AllowOverride All 
        Require all granted
        Allow from All 
 
    FallbackResource /index.php
 
    </Directory>
 
    <Directory /var/www/si2a/public/bundles>
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>
 
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/si2a_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/si2a_access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

When i try to access the site, i found this error :
**No route found for "GET /si2afama"**

Since, it is a Routing issus, here are some files's contain :

**si2a/config/packages/routing.yaml**

```
framework:
    router:
        utf8: true
```

**si2a/config.routes.yaml**

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index
```

**si2a/public/index.php.**

```
<?php
use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';
if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);
    Debug::enable();
}
if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}
if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}
$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I don't really know what to do in order to fix the issus.

May someone help me, please. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any route with name `si2afama` defined.

Comment: Yes @Lounis. `si2afama` is the name of the vhost file name and the ServerName's one in this file. If I understand, the indication of the DocumentRoot and the DirectoryIndex redirect to the `route` of the index. Right ?

Comment: If no, where should I add a valid _route_ for `si2afama` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vhost is related to your domain name and directory of source code,
if you want a route name like `si2afama` for your application, you have to add it to symfony routes.

```
# si2a/config.routes.yaml


index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index

si2afama:
    path: /si2afama
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::nameActionFromController
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Lounis. This fixes the issus. But is this change made in the `# si2a/config/routes.yaml` means that each time i change my _#serverName in the vhost_, like `si2afama.tld` for example, i should adapt this yaml file and the add a corresponding route in my source code ?

Comment: `ServerName` is the host name of your application, `si2afama` is a route only, an example with this url: `http://si2afama.tld/si2afama`, this part `http://si2afama.tld` is the host name you make it what you want it's related to your server (apache here), `/si2afama` is the route (or path / uri) it's related to your symfony application. You don't have to adapt symfony routes if you change domain name.

Answer (score 0):

try to install this package **composer require symfony/apache-pack** it will create a .htaccess file that'll fix your problem

Comment: **...:/var/www/si2a$ composer require symfony/apache-pack**
.. **I install that package** as you can see in the comman line. The .htaccess file has been created in the /public directory. The problem is still here after i try the access

Comment: check if mod_rewrite module for Apache is enabled

Comment: It is since the begining. I enabled it with **a2enmod rewrite**. *Module rewrite already enabled*, when i check

Comment: Any other solution ? I really don't understand what is the problem.